# Optimizing initialization on maps: forwarding the key

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap, initialization, unordered-map

I've got a question that should be interesting. I'd like to "*forward initialize*" an item in a `std::unordered_map` upon construction.

These are the details. I've got a hash map from `std::string` to a custom class `prop`, which in my dreams, would initialize a member variable calculating the hash of the string **passed to** `std::unordered_map::operator[]`.

This is a handy code I've written, but I don't know where to start.

Why this trouble? Because I'd like to avoid something like "if the string is NOT in the container calculate the hash; do stuff with `prop`". Avoiding this `if` could be something that might affect my performances. So the constructor, as well as the hashing, will be executed only once, when the map adds a new item in the container. It would be great.

Any hints?

Thanks & Cheers!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class prop
{
public:
    prop(std::string s = "") : s_(s), hash_(std::hash<std::string>()(s))
    {
        // Automagically forwarding the string in the unordered_map...
    };

    std::string s_;
    std::size_t hash_;
    int x;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // Forward the std::string to the prop constructor... but how?
    std::unordered_map<std::string, prop> map;

    map["ABC"].x = 1;
    map["DEF"].x = 2;
    map["GHI"].x = 3;
    map["GHI"].x = 9; // This should not call the constructor: the hash is there already

    std::cout << map["ABC"].x << " : " << map["ABC"].s_ << " : " << map["ABC"].hash_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << map["DEF"].x << " : " << map["DEF"].s_ << " : " << map["DEF"].hash_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << map["GHI"].x << " : " << map["GHI"].s_ << " : " << map["GHI"].hash_ << std::endl;

    std::cout << map["XXX"].x << " : " << map["XXX"].s_ << " : " << map["XXX"].hash_ << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just store `prop` in an `std::unordered_set` with appropriate `hash` and equality operations?

Comment: I could change containers, but how can this avoid using a nasty `if`? It's not simply an equality that I need that hash for. In an actual class I would store `K` hashes calculated from the given string.

Comment: I guess you should have a look at C++14's upcoming features, like lookup of elements based on a different value. See C++14's [std::unordered_set::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use your prop class as a key, instead of string:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

class prop
{
public:
    prop(std::string s = "") : s_(s), hash_(std::hash<std::string>()(s))
    {
        // Automagically forwarding the string in the unordered_map...
    };

    std::string s_;
    std::size_t hash_;
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    // Forward the std::string to the prop constructor... but how?
    std::unordered_map<prop, int, ...> map( ... );

    prop pABC( "ABC" ), pDEF( "DEF" ), pGHI( "GHI" );

    map[pABC] = 1;
    map[pDEF] = 2;
    map[pGHI] = 3;
    map[pGHI] = 9; 

    std::cout << map[pABC] << " : " << pABC.s_ << " : " << pABC.hash_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << map[pDEF] << " : " << pDEF.s_ << " : " << pDEF.hash_ << std::endl;
    std::cout << map[pGHI] << " : " << pGHI.s_ << " : " << pGHI.hash_ << std::endl;

    prop pXXX( "XXX" );
    std::cout << map[pXXX] << " : " << pXXX.s_ << " : " << pXXX.hash_ << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I omitted custom hash and compare function, the idea should be clear without it.

Comment: That's really good. Except for my mathematical modeling. I would like a map `M : string -> prop`, for instance, you are suggesting to model my problem with its dual `M* : prop -> string`. Not easy to justify, but acceptable!